# Mapbox: Problem with Line rendering on a Snapshot

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I've created a `LineLayer` and `GeoJsonSource` in this way:

```
List<Point> routeCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
for(LatLng latLng: newLatLngs){
   routeCoordinates.add(Point.fromLngLat(latLng.getLongitude(),latLng.getLatitude()));
}

GeoJsonSource lineSource = new GeoJsonSource("route-line-layer-source",LineString.fromLngLats(routeCoordinates));

LineLayer lineLayer = new LineLayer("route-line-layer","route-line-layer-source")
                              .withProperties(PropertyFactory.lineColor(ColorUtils.colorToRgbaString(Color.BLUE)),
                                              PropertyFactory.lineDasharray(new Float[] {0.01f, 2f}),
                                              PropertyFactory.lineWidth(5f),
                                              PropertyFactory.lineCap(Property.LINE_CAP_ROUND),
                                              PropertyFactory.lineJoin(Property.LINE_JOIN_ROUND))
                              .withSourceLayer("route-line-layer-source");
```

After that I create a new `Style.Builder`, `MapSnapshotterOptions` and pass them to the `MapSnapshotter` object:

```
Style.Builder builder1 = new Style.Builder()
                           .fromUri(chosenStyleMode)
                           .withLayer(lineLayer);

MapSnapshotter.Options options = new MapSnapshotter.Options(mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth(), mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredHeight())
                                        .withRegion(mMapboxMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds)
                                        .withCameraPosition(cu.getCameraPosition(mMapboxMap))
                                        .withStyleBuilder(builder1);

mapSnapshotter = new MapSnapshotter(RunningActivity.this, options);
```

The image gets rendered, but the line doesn't appear on the style.

Why it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem today, I fixed it by also including the `GeoJsonSource` in the style.

```
Style.Builder builder1 = new Style.Builder()
                           .fromUri(chosenStyleMode)
                           .withSource(lineSource)
                           .withLayer(lineLayer);
```

Comment: You're right! But I'm quite confused, because I've set two times the source: Once when specifying the GeoJsonSource in the ```LineLayer```'s constructor and then once more when calling ```.withSourceLayer()```

Comment: I have told the Mapbox team to update their examples, since they are using ```.withStyle()``` which is deprecated.