# Android Mapbox, Setting LineLayer on Snapshot results

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Environment: Mapbox Sdk Ver: 10.10.0

I'm now struggling with snapshot results using [Snapshotter] which is embedded class of mapbox.map

I can check LineLayer has drawn perfectly on my MapView before taking snapshots, but after I take a snapshot and check on my local directory(I can see .PNG image files taken), LineLayer is never drawn on the map...

I've also checked documents(of course I might've missed)
and found these
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/legacy/maps/examples/share-a-snapshot/,
[Mapbox: Problem with Line rendering on a Snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730115/mapbox-problem-with-line-rendering-on-a-snapshot)
It seemed pretty possible to get the result I wanted otherwise it was legacy code and I was not able to find replaceable methods for **.withStyleBuilder(builder1);**

I really appreciate any advices or help